# Java Servlet program to separate Image Strings using Array or Array List

Tags: java, arrays, servlets, arraylist

In my java servlet program i am getting images from android application.I want to encode again decode image. If i got two images from android: [abc,def].It is decoded  using MyHelper.decodeImage1(a).
Now problem comes in next step. I want to encode decoded image again. Yes it do encoding. But result is in a single string abcdef. How can i separate two images to send it back to android? How should i manage loop or array in loop. I have tried alot but can't differentiate abc and def. Please help

```
 String imageString=request.getParameter("image");
 // image comees in format [abc,def,efg... and son on]

        imageString=imageString.replace("[", "");
        imageString=imageString.replace("]", "");
        imageString=imageString.replace(" " , "");

        String[] r = imageString.split(",");

for(int i=0; i<r.length;i++){

                String a=r[i];
                System.out.println("In loop = "+i);

                byte[] imageByteArray = MyHelper.decodeImage1(a);

            String encodedimageByteArray=Base64.encodeBytes(imageByteArray) ;
            ArrayList<String> StringImages =  new ArrayList<String>();
            StringImages.add(encodedimageByteArray);
            response.getWriter().write(encodedimageByteArray);


                }
```

Comment: Well what do you want the response to look like? You'll need to work out some separator to insert between each pair of images. (It's not clear why you're creating a list of images on each iteration of the loop, by the way.)

Comment: @JonSkeet [abc,def]..String should be this

Comment: or abc,def. How can i separate abcdef. Two strings abc and def concatenate in a single string abcdef

Comment: @JonSkeet i have added code for clarification

Comment: Well you call `write` to write a string... so you can write whatever you want. For example, at the start of the loop: `if (i != 0) { response.getWriter.write(",")) }`. If you want to put it in square brackets you'll need a little bit more work, but fundamentally you're just writing strings to a writer.

Comment: @JonSkeet no need for square brackets...abc,def is ok. But i am not getting it. , should be added in encodedimageByteArray string, after iterating each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is call `write` appropriately with the text you want to write. For example:

```
Writer writer = response.getWriter();
writer.write("[");
for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
     if (i != 0) {
         writer.write(","); // Separate this item from the previous one
     }
     byte[] bytes = MyHelper.decodeImage1(r[i]);
     String base64 = Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);
     writer.write(base64);
}
writer.write("]");
```

Comment: no need for square brackets...abc,def is ok. But i am not getting it. , should be added in encodedimageByteArray string, after iterating each image.

Comment: i want to use only 1 writer.write(base64). base64 string should be [abc,def] or abc,def

Comment: @user3118495: You can't do that, because `,` isn't part of base64 encoding. `[abc,def]` simply isn't a valid base64 string. *Why* would you only want to call `write` once?

Comment: @yes once only please. I can make my string abc,def...and so on.then i write the string to app.

Comment: @user3118495: But that's *not* a base64 string. "Yes" doesn't answer my question about *why* you don't want to call `write` more than once. What do you think will go wrong? Yes, you *could* create a `StringBuilder`, build everything in that and then call `write(builder.toString())` but it's pointless.